# How different was Dante's spoken dialect from the language of the Divina Commedia?

Tags: regional, history

It is often said that Dante invented the Italian language, but how different was the dialect Dante spoke from the language of his *Divina Commedia*?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I'd phrase it a little differently. Even though Dante had an enormous importance in the history of Italian language, nobody says that he “invented” it. At the very least, the whole of 13th century was rich in great Sicilian, Northern and Tuscan poets who wrote in varieties of “Italian”, several of whom Dante himself acknowledged as masters and colleagues, and we are ignoring earlier literary works, such as the _Ritmo cassinese_, the _Ritmo di Sant'Alessio_ and the compositions by Francis of Assisi...

Comment: ...and even earlier non-literary works, and the fact that written sources come some time after the use of a language as a spoken mean of communication.

Comment: Nevertheless, Dante [invented some words](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/neologismi_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/).

Comment: For a comparison, you could try to look in the language of the *Decameron* that I expect to be much closer to the vernacular (although certainly not identical)

Comment: Indeed, @Charo, and several idioms and so on. But it is a truism that he did not _invent_ Italian language (or else nobody could have read his non-Latin works), since it had been in use for a couple of centuries before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Italy, in XIII century, the **spoken language** was the vernacular language, the **“official” language** was Latin.
Latin, however, remained in use among a minority of educated persons, mostly priests and monks of the Catholic Church, who probably used it often as a spoken language.
So you have to consider that the spoken language was different depending on the person they were talking to.
So in everyday life, Dante spoke **Latin** (with literate people) or **vernacular language**.
Surely the language that Dante used was not too casual, you have also to consider that he was a cultivated person, so his vernacular language was surely different from that spoken by poor plebs (there were a lot of illiterate).

As @DaG said, Dante is not the “inventor” of the Italian language, but some people says that ([Italian Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dante_Alighieri) defines him as “The father of the Italian Language”) because his Divine Comedy, widely considered the most important poem of the Middle Ages and the greatest literary work in the Italian language, was entirely written in vernacular language, the dialect used in everyday life by the common people of his time.

Dante, in his letter “*Epistola XIII*” to “Cangrande della Scala” wrote (in Latin):

31. Et per hoc patet, quod comedia dicitur presens opus. Nam si ad materiam respiciamus, a principio horribilis et fetida est, quia Infernus, in fine prospera, desiderabilis et grata, quia Paradisus; ad modum loquendi, remissus est modus et humilis, quia locutio vulgaris, in qua et muliercule comunicant.  32. Sunt et alia genera narrationum poeticarum, scilicet carmen bucolicum, elegia, satira, et sententia votiva, ut etiam per Oratium patere potest in sua Poetria; sed de istis ad presens nihil dicendum est (Dante, Epistole, XIII, 31-32).”

*“Therefore it is clear why this work is called Comedy. In fact, if we look at the content, initially horrible and repugnant, because it describes the Inferno, in the end it appears positive, desirable and pleasant, because it illustrates Paradise; as for the expression, a measured and humble language is used, as it uses the vulgar language in which women express themselves. But there are also other kinds of poetic narratives, such as bucolic poem, elegy, satire and votive singing, as Horace explains in his poetic Art; but, in this context, it is not appropriate to speak about”.*

Comment: Are you sure about "Karma"?

Comment: @DaG sorry, I meant "poem"... I edited my answer.